# Independence given Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I'm currently learning about conditional probability and came across a question I couldn't answer:

If we know P(A | B,C) = P(A | B) and P (B | A,C) = P(B | A), show that C is independent of (A,B) given non-zero joint entries.

Firstly, what exactly is meant by "non-zero joint entries" and how would one show this? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that non-zero joint entries means that the probabilities of the conditioned events are not zero.

Comment: You should show that P(C | A,B) = P(C). Try to use the definition of conditional probability and from there it is just algebra.